# Azure AKS does not have D2 v4 nodes listed in selection

Tags: azure, aks

Want to select D2 v4 (0GB Temp storage) nodes for my AKS node pool, but this node size is not available.

Now we are using D2s v3 (16GB temp storage).
That temp storage is not used and also is not that cheap (premium p10 ssd).

Azure Pricing calculators have this node size listed, so we had expectation it will be available.

Region: West Europe

Is there any way how to request that specific node size or where could we find information about why it is not available?

Or is this because for AKS there always has to be some sort of temp storage for kubernetes management?